# Is there a workaround on Client side for the failing FTP data and control channel association?

Tags: firewall, ftp, cloud, zos

I have a Cloud app - SecureGatway firewall - zOS architecure. I'm on the client side. I can open an FTP control connection between the client and the server with the client script (PHP) but the data connection fails. I can also change settings on the firewall (secure gateway) so I have more control than the client script.

I have read some articles and questions here so I understand that there is passive and active mode and control and data channel. Example: [FTP Connection Modes (Active vs. Passive)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes)

I [also read](https://superuser.com/questions/1203836/ftp-server-active-mode) that the router might be failing to acquire the two connections (FTP control and data). Is there a workaround that I can implement on the client side to make this association or whatever? I can run FTP commands on server side example.. Maybe that could help?

Edited based on comments: 
 - I tried passive mode ftp_pasv () - it resulted to timeout
 - OS: app server runs on: 14.04.1-Ubuntu. Connecting to zOS/MVS

Comment: Have you tried PASV mode and what were the results.  Also, what FTP client and OS are you using so we can identify the specific commands needed.

Comment: If both sides are behind some firewall or NAT as it might be the case here (not fully clear, but common for cloud setups on one side and company/private internet access on the other) there is likely  no workaround, i.e. the firewall/NAT on at least one side must be able to explicitly deal with FTP instead of just forwarding data. FTP is always a trouble when NAT/firewalls are involved, better use protocols like sftp (SSH based) which don't have this problem.